# Using variables for creating objects and calling methods in Java

Tags: java, arrays, binding

Hi Everyone I am beginner in java and came across a question like Can I use variables for creating objects and calling methods to reuse the code.

**Tesla.java**

```
public class Tesla extends Car {
    @Override
    public void buy(){
        System.out.println("Tesla bought");
        }
     @Override    
     public void sell(){
        System.out.println("Tesla Sold");
        }
}
```

**Ford.java**

```
public class Ford extends Car {
    @Override
    public void buy(){
        System.out.println("Ford bought");
        }
     @Override    
     public void sell(){
        System.out.println("Ford Sold");
        }
}
```

**Car.java**

```
public class Car {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[][] arr = {{"Tesla, Buy"},{"Ford", "Sell"},{"Benz", "Sell"}};
            Car car = new Tesla();
            car.buy();
            Car car = new Ford();
            car.sell();
        }
    
        public void buy() {
            System.out.println("Car bought");           
        }
        
        public void sell() {
            System.out.println("Car Sold");         
        }
    
    }
```

Here instead of creating each object I just want to use one for loop and create respective object and respective method based on the array elements.
Logic like below.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   String[][] arr = {{"Tesla, Buy"},{"Ford", "Sell"},{"Benz", "Sell"}};
    for(int i = 0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
    Car car = new arr[i][0]();
    car.arr[i][1];
    }
}
```

How to achieve above logic? Is this something achievable in Java? I searched in google couldn't find relevant questions or problems. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**Note:-** I don't want a workaround I just want to know the if logic is achievable using any advanced java concepts I am unaware of.

Comment: I'm sure, you can already find something on SO, but Look at [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to instantiate objects of various subclasses according to string inputs, you have at least two options:

- Reflection
- Builder pattern

## Reflection

As [commented by Nikolaus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65193992/using-variables-for-creating-objects-and-calling-methods-in-java#comment115256255_65193992), one route is to use Java’s reflection facility. This is the “magic” way, where you would find at runtime the name of the class matching your string input. For example, `"Tesla"` string would lead you to loading an object of type `Class` representing the `Tesla` class you wrote at compile time. You would call methods on that `Class` object to create an instance of your subclass. In other words, you are programmatically doing a roundabout replacement for the code `new Tesla(…)`.

I do not recommend going the reflection route. This is not “normal” Java app programming. Reflection is usually done only in certain kinds of frameworks and in special rare circumstances.

## Builder pattern

The other route more commonly used is the [*Builder* pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). You define another class called something like `CarBuilder`. You pass your text values into one or more methods of an object of this type `CarBuilder`. Those methods validate the inputs.

When done setting up the various pieces of input, you eventually call a method conventionally called `build`. That method produces and returns an object of type `Car`. That `Car` object is actually from a subclass, is actually a `Tesla` or `Ford`.

```
CarBuilder builder = new CarBuilder() ;
builder.setBrand( "Tesla" ) ;
builder.set… = … ;
…
Car car = builder.build() ;  // Actually a `Tesla` subclass object.
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than create different classes (Tesla, Ford) that inherit from a superclass (Car), just pass in parameters to your Car class methods:

```
public class Car {
    
        public void Buy(String brand) {
            System.out.println(brand+" bought");           
        }
        
        public void Sell(String brand) {
            System.out.println(brand+" Sold");         
        }
    
    }
```

I would also move the main method out to a separate Runner class. Its only responsibility would be to run the program and nothing else. That way you decouple the classes that implement your model (Car...) from the classes used to run the program.

Additionally, my example is a bit weak in the sense that I have to pass in the brand for each method. What you should do instead is introduce the notion of a constructor in your Car class and the notion of a [class attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_class_attributes.asp). Your code then becomes

```
public Class Car{
    private String brand;
    public Car(String brand){
        this.brand = brand;
    }
    public void Buy(String brand) {
        System.out.println(brand+" bought");           
    }

    public void Sell(String brand) {
        System.out.println(brand+" Sold");         
    }
}
```

One last thing: methods typically don't start with a capital letter in Java so you should rename Buy and Sell to buy and sell.

Your second requirement is also to parameterize the action (buy or sell). You can apply the same principle i.e. have a generic method (doAction()) that will now take in 2 parameters: the car brand and the action you want to do. But IMHO that's pushing it too far and losing value.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for your comment. I don't want a workaround I just want to know the if logic is achievable using any advanced java concepts I am unaware of.